# How to install the latest 1004.x cumulocity UI package [ng1]?

Tags: cumulocity

How can I update my custom app to the latest (current 1004.x) cumulocity UI package using the old ng1 command line tools?

Updating to a previous 9.x version works fine:

```
>c8y install 9.20.13
Installing 9.20.13 UI Package...
npm+ cumulocity-ui-build@9.20.13
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 30.478s
found 0 vulnerabilities
9.20.13 UI package installed
```

But trying to update to any version >= 1004.0 fails:

```
>c8y install 1004.0.6 
1004.0.6 UI not found
```

By the way, `c8y install latest` always installs version `9.20.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cumulocity Web SDK got migrated to ngx (Angular 2+) which means you need to upgrade your application as the old SDK and build tooling is not supported anymore. The following table gives you an overview:
[image]

So basically you can just use the tooling until version `9.25.x`, afterwards you need to use the new [@c8y/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@c8y/cli) tool. More information about the migration process can be found [here](https://cumulocity.com/guides/web/background/#migrating).

Migrating is quite easy as all ng1 plugins can be integrated into a ngx application:

1. `npm i -g @c8y/cli` install the new tooling
2. `c8ycli new your-app-name cockpit` Create a new app based on the cockpit app.
3. `cd your-app-name && npm install` open the new created folder and install the dependencies
4. Copy your custom plugins to the folder
5. Open `ng1.ts` and replace the not needed plugin references. Reference your custom plugins to point to the cumulocity.json manifest (e.g. `import './my-plugin/cumulocity.json'`)
6. run your app locally `npm start -- -u http://yourinstance.cumulocity.com`
7. Go to your browser and check if the application work (look out for errors in the console as well!): `http://localhost:9000/apps/your-app-name/`
8. Deploy you application if everything is fine: `npm run build && npm run deploy`
9. **done**

Cumulocity applications after version 10.04.x.x are now running Angular (ngx) and angularjs (ngx) at the same time (so-called hybrid applications) which allows you to use the new Angular framework while you can still use your already developed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Installation steps of cumulocity UI has been changed now for version 10.4.

```
curl -s http://resources.cumulocity.com/webapps/ui-releases/deploy.sh | bash -s -- -u management/admin -p <password> -i <instance> -v 1004.3.0
```